# Pattern in one list to compare another list

Tags: python

I am working on a program which has two lists with the same amount of elements

The first list consists of a pattern (Note: pat will always have atleast 2 different elements):

```
pat = ['G', 'H', 'G' ]
```

Then the second list is a list that contains lists.

```
mylist = [['Hello'], ['Hey'], ['Hello']]
```

I need to check the pattern in pat, and see if mylist follows the pattern.

So in this case mylist follows the pattern in pat because mylist[0] == mylist[2] and mylist[1] could
be anything because it doesnt have to follow any other pattern according to pat.

So the program should return the elements in mylist which DO NOT follow the pattern in pat:

```
[]
```

But if mylist did not follow the pattern in pat, then the program should return a list with only the elements in mylist which did not follow the patter in the same order, here are some function calls:

```
>>>pat_check(['G', 'W', 'G', 'G'], [[12], ['E'], [12], [13]])    #[13], [12], [12] should be the same but they are not therefor the program returns all those values
[[12], [12], [13]]

>>>pat_check(['G', 'H', 'G'], [['G'], ['H'], ['L']])    #['G'] and ['L'] are supposed to be the same but they are not, the program will output the 2 elements that should be the same but are not
[['G'], ['L']]

>>>pat_check(['G', 'H', 'G'], [['Hello'], ['Hey'], ['Hello']])  # everything is correct
[]
```

I am really new to python, it would be really appreciated to use easy to understand form and just basic methods. (no import re and other stuff like that)

**Q:** Is there any algorithm to do this?

Comment: So is there any particular issue you are having or are you looking for algorithm to do that?

Comment: I am just looking or algorithm doing that, I tried to using a nested for loop, but I am not sure how to  because a for loop only looks at 1 element at a time, and here i need to look at more then 1 at a time

Comment: In which case your first question should be returning [[12],[12],[13]]. Provide more clear understanding of the logic behind pat_check. I also believe, if you can infer the logic and completely understand it you can codify it easily as well.

Comment: the reason 12 12 13 would be returned is because the program must show ALL the things is mylist that must be equal. So the output would be 12 12 13, so its saying if all these things were equal to each other then the program would return nothing sorry for being unclear

Answer (score 1):

Use a `dict` to keep track of what you encountered:

```
def pat_check(pat, mylist):
    dct = {}
    res = []
    for p, q in zip(pat, mylist):
        if dct.setdefault(p, q) != q:
            res.append(q)
    return res
```

Note: You have to add code to handle `pat` and `mylist` of different lengths.

Also, `pat_check(['G', 'H', 'G'], [['G'], ['H'], ['L']])` should be `[['L']]`, which is not what you wrote in your post.

Using list comprehension:

```
def pat_check(pat, mylist):
    dct = {}
    return [q for p, q in zip(pat, mylist) if dct.setdefault(p, q) != q]
```

EDIT:

```
from collections import defaultdict


def key_vals(pat, mylist):
    res = defaultdict(list)
    for p, q in zip(pat, mylist):
        res[p].append(q)
    return res


def pat_check(pat, mylist):
    res = []
    for p, vals in key_vals_order(pat, mylist).items():
        # could be vals[1:], but that makes a copy so it should be benched with
        # actual data
        if any(v != vals[0] for v in vals):
            res.extend(vals)
    return res
```

If you care about order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


def key_vals(pat, mylist):
    res = OrderedDict()
    for p, q in zip(pat, mylist):
        res.setdefault(p, []).append(q)
    return res
```

Comment: This is definitely more Pythonic than my suggestion.

Comment: for (['G', 'H', 'G'], [['G'], ['H'], ['L']]) it should be G and L because it has to return the things in the list that do not match, how do we know that G or L is the right one?

Comment: That really depends on how the problem is defined. What if there were a case of two pairs, such as `pattern = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A'], mylist = ['B', 'B', 'C', 'C']`? I think it might be up to you to decide how to resolve that.

Comment: yes you are very correct. It is my fault I should have said in the original post but the elements in pattern will have atleast 2 different things. i will update, very sorry for the confusion

Comment: I don't think that was what @Kyle_S-C was getting at. This type of pattern matching can always lead to ambiguities. In something like `pattern = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B'], mylist = ['C', 'C', 'D', 'E']`, what is incorrect? Do you count the `(A, D)` pair as incorrect because `(A, C)` came first, or would you count both `(A, C)` and `(A, D)` as incorrect?

Comment: so if we would have what u typed up there, the function would return C C D, all of the elements that should be the same but are not

Comment: im getting an error when running the first part, TypeError: first argument must be callable

Comment: Also, I know I am kind of being picky but, i dont really understand the from collections import defaultdict, could you just write it plain code? no importing or anything? if it is possible, and if you have time, if you dont want to do this question anymore its ok you have been really helpful and I really appreciate that

Comment: I fixed the `TypeError`, `defaultdict(f)[key]` is equivalent to: `dict[key] if key in dict else f()`

Comment: if you have time later could you try to write it without importing anything? like the most basic python ever? Sorry for bugging you alot

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
def pat_check(pattern, list_to_check):
    pattern_dict = {}
    not_matching = []
    for i, value in enumerate(pattern):
        try:
            if pattern_dict[value] != list_to_check[i]:
                not_matching.append(list_to_check[i])
        except KeyError:
            pattern_dict[value] = list_to_check[i]
    return not_matching
```

Bear in mind that there's a bit of an ambiguous situation in your example:

> > > pat_check(['G', 'H', 'G'], [['G'], ['H'], ['L']])    #['G'] and ['L'] are supposed to be the same but they are not [['G'], ['L']]

This algorithm only outputs `['L']` as it considers `['G']` to match with itself.

Comment: the 'G' in pat has nothing do to with mylist[0]

Comment: the program should just output the things in mylist that SHOULD rhyme. not one thing that should be changed for everything to be perfext

Comment: In which case your first question should be returning [[12],[12],[13]]. Provide more clear understanding of the logic behind pat_check. I also believe, if you can infer the logic and completely understand it you can codify it easily as well.

Comment: the reason 12 12 13 would be returned is because the program must show ALL the things is mylist that must be equal. So the output would be 12 12 13, so its saying if all these things were equal to each other then the program would return nothing sorry for being unclear